# How many orbits are there on the set of upper triangular matrices?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

$G:=$upper triangular $GL_2(\Bbb R)$, $X:=\Bbb R^2$, group action: $\pi_g(x)=gx.$

Let $x$ be $(0\ 0)^T$, then, $gx=(0\ 0)^T$ for all $g$ so
\begin{equation}
    Orb((0\ 0)^T)=(0\ 0)^T.
\end{equation}
Now, take $x:=(1\ 0)^T$, then
\begin{equation}
 \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
0 & c
\end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1  \\
0 
\end{array} \right)= 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a \\
0
\end{array} \right).
\end{equation}
Similarly, take $x:=(0\ 1)^T$, then
\begin{equation}
 \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
0 & c
\end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0  \\
1 
\end{array} \right)= 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
b \\
c
\end{array} \right).
\end{equation}

So we have three orbits here? But then what about the vectors say, $(s\ t)$ for example where $s$ and $t$ are non-zero? I was trying to do this question similar to an example gone through with me in a class, and the lecturer seemed to just use these vectors to determine the orbit. So am a bit confused here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: If $b\ne 0$, then $\begin{pmatrix}b\\c\end{pmatrix}$ has only non-zero entries.

Comment: oh right, since it has to be invertible. so there's only one orbit then, the set of column vectors that are non-zero?

Comment: How would you go from $\pmatrix{b\\c}$ to $\pmatrix{a\\0}$?